# Main Activity and Splash Screen Priority Prblm

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a problem with Main Activity and Splash Screen.There is intent filter both of them

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When I remove intent-filter from MainActivity the app cannot open.What must I do ?

Comment: Basically,what you want to do?

Comment: splash screen is different activity?

Comment: if splash screen is different activity then you need to launch your main activity (using `startActivity`) from the splash screen activity.

Comment: Unrelated fact: it is unadvised to have a splash screen, try to think a way to start your app right away and let the user directly enters it

Comment: Yes I got it I have java folder like that but I think there is different problem.There is intent filter about MainActivity from start.

There is two intent filter about main and splash.And when I remove intent that is related with main activity my app cannot open.

Comment: post the rest of your manifest please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>            
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

SplashScreen Class

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it I have java folder like that but I think there is different problem.There is intent filter about MainActivity from start.

There is two intent filter about main and splash.And when I remove intent that is related with main activity my app cannot open.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.again.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.again.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to have intent filter only for your splash screen. And you need to start main activity from your splash screen activity.

Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.example.SplashScreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity"></activity>
```

Start main activity from splash screen and finish it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Yes I got it I have java folder like that but I think there is different problem.There is intent filter about MainActivity from start.

There is two intent filter about main and splash.And when I remove intent that is related with main activity my app cannot open.

Comment: You need to have at least one activity with intent filter with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`. Make sure that this intent filter is associated with SplashActivity.